# force an iOS user to enter his own ID to use the device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I'm trying to think of a way (if exists) that each user who uses the device will enter his ID so only authenticated users could use the device.
Why?
I have a few iOS devices in my department and I want to be able to monitor who was last to use the device, so if it was lost within the people in my department it will be easier to track it.
any ideas?
is there a way to write a proper app to do that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many ways of authenticating users (e.g. use a `UIAlertView`). You'll have to be a more specific.

Comment: '**...so only authenticated users could use the device**' - as in you have to go through your app before accessing any of the device's other features? No, this is outright impossible on a device that isn't jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do that without jailbreaking and doing some really custom app development.  The OS does not give you an option for intercepting user credentials.

You could write an application to simply authenticate a person against a web-service and store authentication information there.  Then just make it a policy to always fire up that application and log in before using the device for anything else.

I have a couple of enterprise applications that do something similar.  Each user logs in at the beginning of their shift and then logs out at the end.